# How to get Amazon MWS Developer ID

Tags: amazon-mws

I am required to write an Excel Macro to get order and inventory details for my client (using Amazon MWS).

But my client needs my developer ID to grant me access to his account.

I searched a lot but didn't find any link where I can register as a developer and get my Amazon Developer Identifier.

From where I can register as developer and get my developer ID?

Reference: https://developer.amazonservices.ca/gp/mws/faq.html#developForSeller

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find your developer ID using the "Sign up for MWS" wizard located here: https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/registration/register.html

You will need to have a seller account on the "Professional" plan or higher. If you don't already have one, you can sign up here:
http://www.amazon.com/gp/seller-account/mm-summary-page.html

Note that this will only work for vendors on the American version of Amazon - if your client is selling on one of the localized Amazon sites like Amazon.ca, then you will need a developer ID and seller account from the localized sites. In the case of Europe, a European account can authorize any other European account (e.g. a UK seller can authorize a French Amazon account.)

Comment: joshubrown : On signing up for mws, I got only `merchant ID, Marketplace ID, AWS Access Key ID, Secret Key` But no developer account number. Any ideas?

Comment: I have signed up for MWS with Professional plan but it requires $39.99 per month payment (even for development)? Any idea if I can get a free trial or a free developer account?

Comment: I finaly figured this out.... it is actualy there you just dont realize because you are lookinga the 4 left aligned id's. look on the right of the bottom box that says Developer account identifier and credentials for developer account number XXXXXXXXXX*

Comment: I checked 'I want to use an application to access my Amazon seller account with MWS'. It asks Application Name and Application's Developer Account Number. How do I create MWS Application's Developer Account ?

Comment: @SoorajlalKG Did you find the solution for that? And did you find a way to register as a developer without paying 39.99$?

Comment: There is (as of August 2017) no free way around this. You have to register as a seller and pay the monthly fee for a "Professional" selling account before Amazon will give you MWS credentials.

Answer (score 11):

Apparently, you **must** have an eligible Amazon Seller account in order to obtain a Developer Account Identifier, and those accounts start at **$39.99 per month**.

There are multiple discussions on the amazon sellers forum about this. This is probably the most on-topic:

https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=2958433

It appears there truly is no free nor less expensive option, and that Amazon simply *does* double-dip and charge **both** the actual seller *and the developer* just to use MWS at all.

Answer (score 5):

Once logged in to your paid seller account... in the upper right corner of the screen, Settings > User Permissions, then under the text "Amazon MWS Developer Access Keys" press the button "Visit Developer Credentials".

If you already have a Developer ID but it is no longer working, you have to apply again here:  https://sellercentral.amazon.com/mws/register/warning

Before applying, I suggest you study hard the information in these links.  I think if you answer even one of the questions wrong while applying for the developer ID, you will be denied.  Also, if you get denied, they don't tell you the reason
http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_DataProtectionPolicy.html
http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_AcceptableUsePolicy.html

In addition, FYI:

It used to be that anyone with a paid seller account could get developer credentials just by clicking some buttons.  However, Amazon is now vetting developers with a more through process which could take up to 30 days.

Comment: This is sooooo helpful. I was cracking my head for days just to find this Developer Credentials, which somehow I realized my account doesn't have permission to access the _User Permissions Page_ anymore 

Answer (score 4):

From Amazon:

> **I am a developer and I want to develop software using MWS for another Amazon seller. What should I do?**
>
> Only the owner of the Amazon seller account can authorize a third-party to access their seller account. You as the third-party developer must first sign up to use MWS for your own Amazon seller account and keep a record of the MWS developer account identifier that is displayed on the final registration page. Then, give that number to the Amazon seller who wants to use your services as a developer. When the Amazon seller registers, they will use this MWS developer account identifier to grant MWS access to you. Also, they must send their seller account identifiers to you so you can make MWS requests on their behalf. You can give your Amazon sellers the following instructions to guide them through the MWS registration process.

https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/faq.html#faq__developForSeller

Comment: I have already read that FAQ. But I am not able to find a link from where I can register as a developer.

Comment: You should preface your answer by saying, "The following is a quote from Amazon..."  I thought you were asking a new question on SO.

Comment: Argh. This question no longer appears on that page. But the "you [...] must first sign up to use MWS for your own Amazon seller account" part says it all and appears to still be the case today.